# improve code on updating content inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I learned that you can update a content inside div by using jQuery. I want to improve this code as the content is being change after it loads. I want it to be permanent regardless if it's loading or not.

Here's my code.

```
function changeContent () {
  var myelement = document.getElementById("topbarlogin");
  myelement.innerHTML= "HELLO";
}

window.onload = changeContent ;
```

This is my html code

```
<div class="signuplink" id="topbarlogin">Login</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either call your function at the end of your body tag without `window.load` in `script` tag...

It will execute `function()` faster than the `window.load`

***Stack Snippet***

```html
<body>
  <div class="signuplink" id="topbarlogin">Login</div>
  <script>
    function changeContent() {
      var myelement = document.getElementById("topbarlogin");
      myelement.innerHTML = "HELLO";
    }
    changeContent();
  </script>

</body>
```

...Or you can use `DOMContentLoaded` EventListener...it is equivalent to the `$(document).ready()` jQuery

```js
function changeContent() {
  var myelement = document.getElementById("topbarlogin");
  myelement.innerHTML = "HELLO";
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  changeContent();
});
```

```html
<div class="signuplink" id="topbarlogin">Login</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

On DOM Ready use `.html()` to set HTML of `div`.

```js
// This is you DOM Ready
$(function(){
  // Set HTML using jQuery
  $("#topbarlogin").html("HELLO");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="signuplink" id="topbarlogin">Login</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$("#topbarlogin").html("Hello");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)